# What is the user agent string for facebook app from android

Tags: user-agent

What is the user-agent string added when we open facebook app from an android mobile. I want to detect facebook app from android OS using user-agent string, is that achievable. Are there unique user-agent strings for different devices for facebook app

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Obligatory disclaimer: user-agent strings are usually the wrong answer. They change, they're inconsistent, it's a brittle way to detect anything.

That said, testing on a Samsung Galaxy S5, with a freshly installed FB app as of today, I got:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/35.0.0.48.273;]
```

The parts with 'FB' specifially seem to be Facebook information. I'd guess that:

- FB_IAB: Facebook In-App Browser (followed by a version)
- FBAV: Facebook App Version (followed by a version)

The FBAV is shared with the iOS user-agent string as found here: http://mpulp.mobi/2012/01/funky-user-agent-on-facebook-iphone-app/

Comment: Totally agreed with the disclaimer.  That said, `FB_IAB/FB4A` and `FBAN/FBIOS` are documented on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices so looking for those specifically is more acceptable than most User-Agent detection.

Answer (score 2):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Build/LMY47O.H18; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/127.0.0.22.69;]
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930F Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/127.0.0.22.69;]
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; MHA-L29 Build/HUAWEIMHA-L29; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/127.0.0.22.69;]
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14F89 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/96.0.0.45.70;FBBV/60548545;FBDV/iPhone7,2;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/10.3.2;FBSS/2;FBCR/E-Plus;FBID/phone;FBLC/de_DE;FBOP/5;FBRV/0]
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14C92 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/90.0.0.51.69;FBBV/56254015;FBDV/iPhone6,2;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/10.2;FBSS/2;FBCR/1&1;FBID/phone;FBLC/de_DE;FBOP/5;FBRV/0]
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14F89 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/96.0.0.45.70;FBBV/60548545;FBDV/iPhone8,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/10.3.2;FBSS/2;FBCR/o2-de;FBID/phone;FBLC/de_DE;FBOP/5;FBRV/0]
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; G7-L01 Build/HuaweiG7-L01) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/MESSENGER;FBAV/121.0.0.15.70;]
```

[Reference](https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess/issues/804)