# User Agent Strings of Spotify and Shazam Users

Tags: spotify, spotify-app, shazam, spotify-desktop

Are there any known commonalities of all user agent strings for Spotify app/software? Same question for the Shazam mobile app, as well.

For example, the Facebook mobile app has several elements of all their user agent strings that can be used as identifiers, including:

FBAN/
FBAV/
FBBV/
FBDV/

I'm wondering if there are similar identifiers for Spotify and Shazam users. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question here. Which Spotify agent are you referring to?

Comment: Please refer to the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094232/what-is-the-user-agent-string-for-facebook-app-from-android

I'm essentially wondering the same thing, except for Spotify and Shazam, and I'm not necessarily looking for any specific device-type. Does that make sense?